# What is this game with 9 sticks with black and white beads?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]
I found this game at my house, and I don’t know what it’s called, or how to play it. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 5):

BoardGameGeek has a similar game called [Rex](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/6243/rex/versions) which only has 3 beads per peg. But it is basically a 3 in a row game (horizontally, vertically and diagonally) with the twist that the center 3 pegs allow one to form a triangle too. No doubt one could also play a scoring version to see who gets the most points when the pegs are full.

Exactly what you version of the game might be called, or who made it is a mystery. But for such simple games many "folkart" versions have been made.

Comment: It probably is Rex, with the extra beads as spares.